# After substituting Functions in sympy, the evaluation fails to do straightforward derivatives

Tags: python, math, sympy

Last Day I have been bothering with this problem. At first I made a question but after comment of needing a simplified example, I deleted the question and I finally found the "source" of the problem.

I fail to evaluate expressions AFTER substituting Functions by expressions: Following example will show you what I mean:

```
xx     = sy.Symbol('x',real=True)
yy     = sy.Symbol('y',real=True)
FuncT  = sy.Function('F')
TestExp= sy.cos(sy.diff(FuncT(xx,yy),xx)+xx+yy*xx+yy)
print(TestExp.subs({FuncT(xx,yy):xx})).subs({xx:1,yy:0.1})
```

which results

[image]

How can it replace dx/dx = 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `doit`:

```
>>> TestExp.subs({FuncT(xx,yy):xx}).subs({xx:1,yy:0.1}).doit()
-0.588501117255346
```

How to know to use `doit`?

When I print (not `pprint`) the expressions I see

```
cos(Subs(Derivative(x, x), x, 1) + 1.2)
```

I don't want `Subs` there but I don't know much about `Subs` so I
ask for help and read the following:

```
>>> help(Subs)
...
There's no automatic expansion - use the method .doit() to effect all
possible substitutions of the object and also of objects inside the
expression.
...
```

Comment: Wow. Where was I supposed to find this?